# Regex Help required for User-Agent Matching

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, user-agent, iis-10

Have used an online regex learning site (regexr) and created something that works but with my very limited experience with regex creation, I could do with some help/advice.

In IIS10 logs, there is a list for time, date... but I am only interested in the cs(User-Agent) field.

My Regex:

`(scan\-\d+)(?:\w)+\.shadowserver\.org`

which matches these:

```
scan-02.shadowserver.org
scan-15n.shadowserver.org
scan-42o.shadowserver.org
scan-42j.shadowserver.org
scan-42b.shadowserver.org
scan-47m.shadowserver.org
scan-47a.shadowserver.org
scan-47c.shadowserver.org
scan-42a.shadowserver.org
scan-42n.shadowserver.org
scan-42o.shadowserver.org
```

but what I would like it to do is:

1. Match a single number with the option of capturing more than one: scan-2 or scan-02 with an optional letter: scan-2j or scan-02f
2. Append the rest of the User Agent: .shadowserver.org to the regex.

I will then add it to an existing URL Rewrite rule (as a condition) to abort the request.

Any advice/help would be very much appreciated

Tried:

To write a regex for IIS10 to block requests from a certain user-agent

Expected:

It to work on single numbers as well as double/triple numbers with or without a letter.

`(scan\-\d+)(?:\w)+\.shadowserver\.org`

Input Text:

```
scan-2.shadowserver.org
scan-02.shadowserver.org
scan-2j.shadowserver.org
scan-02j.shadowserver.org
scan-17w.shadowserver.org
scan-101p.shadowserver.org
```

UPDATE:

I eventually came up with this:

```
scan\-[0-9]+[a-z]{0,1}\.shadowserver\.org
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *explanation* of your regex pattern if you only want the solution, then go directly to the end.

`(scan\-\d+)(?:\w)+`

`(scan\-\d+)` Group1: match the word `scan` followed by a literal `-`, you escaped the hyphen with a `\`, but if you keep it without escaping it also means a literal `-` in this case, so you don't have to escape it here, the `-` followed by `\d+` which means one more digit from `0-9` there must be at least one digit, then the value inside the group will be saved inside the first capturing group.

`(?:\w)+` non-capturing group, `\w` one character which is equal to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, but the the plus `+` sign after the non-capturing group `(?:\w)+`, means match the whole group one or more times, the group contains only `\w` which means it will match one or more word character, note the non-capturing group here is redundant and we can use `\w+` directly in this case.

Taking two examples:

*The first example:* `scan-02.shadowserver.org`

`(scan\-\d+)(?:\w)+`

- `scan` will match the word `scan` in `scan-02` and the `\-` will match the hyphen after scan `scan-`, the `\d+` which means match one or more digit at first it will match the `02`  after `scan-` and the value would be `scan-02`, then the `(?:\w)+` part, the plus `+` means match one or more word character, at least match one, it will try to match the period `.` but it  will fail, because the period `.` is not a word character, at this point, do you think it is over ? No , the regex engine will return back to the previous `\d+`, and this time it will only match the `0` in `scan-02`, and the value `scan-0` will be saved inside the first capturing group, then the `(?:\w)+` part will match the `2` in `scan-02`, but why the engine returns back to `\d+` ? this is because you used the `+` sign after `\d+`, `(?:\w)+` which means match at least one digit, and one word character respectively, so it will try to do what it is asked to do literally.

*The second example:* `scan-2.shadowserver.org`

`(scan\-\d+)(?:\w)+`

- `(scan\-\d+)` will match `scan-2`, `(?:\w)+` will try to match the period after `scan-2` but it fails and this is the important point here, then it will go back to the beginning of the string `scan-2.shadowserver.org` and try to match `(scan\-\d+)` again but starting from the character `c` in the string , so `s` in `(scan\-\d+)` faild to match `c`, and it will continue trying, at the end it will fail.

---

Simple solution:

```
(scan-\d+[a-z]?)\.shadowserver\.org
```

*Explanation*

`(scan-\d+[a-z]?)`, Group1: will capture the word `scan`, followed by a literal `-`, followed by `\d+` one or more digits, followed by an optional small letter `[a-z]?` the `?` make the `[a-z]` part optional, if not used, then the `[a-z]` means that there must be only one small letter.

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gStgC0/1)